# Is it possible to lay a block adjacent to another without looking at the face of the existing block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to build a bridge over a valley to allow fast travelling between 2 areas. The only way I can see to do it is this:

1. Build steps up to the level I need.
2. Move right to the end of the last block placed
3. Turn around so I can see a bit of the face of the last block
4. Place the block so it extends the length of the bridge
5. Repeat from step 2.

This is slow because you you have to carefully navigate yourself to the precarious edge of a block each time.

**Is there an easy way to place a block adjacent to an existing block without having to look back from beyond the edge of the existing block?**

If my description doesn't make sense I may need to resort to ascii art.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you sneak <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> you don't have to be so careful since you don't fall while sneaking.

If you are putting down that is level just snaek and walk backwards constantly and place your blocks.

A trick to get you stay in sneak mode (on Windows) is to press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> down then press and release <kbd>ALT</kbd> release your <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key and click back into the game with your mouse.  You should stay in sneak mode untill you press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> again, meaning you can move around without falling off any ledges.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sneaking

Comment: I forgot about this feature - I'll have to start using it more

Comment: Instead of that little bug involving ALT you can also set your crouch key to be CAPS LOCK at which point it becomes a toggle, not a hold - this works definitely on a Mac and I'm pretty certain on PC as well. On Linux, it depends on the version of Java you had and the speed Minecraft will run at, which is actually a concern on all three systems but on recent Macs is just so not frequent I don't think of it.

Comment: @badp , thank you a ton! I wasn't sure it was the same everywhere and didn't know it was this high.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows, you can enable sticky keys by pressing Shift 5 times in a row and clicking Yes. Then press shift twice; it will stay in sneak mode until you push shift again.

Comment: I find this kind of cheaty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this mod. http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1628264-146-vanillaforge-overtheedge-mod/

It's the easiest way to build bridges.